# How can I restrict results to exact match when jQuery .match() is returning partial match from list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery filter function that searches an unordered list for any exact match and then removesClass if found. However some list items may contain values that partially match such as AI and AI Ethics. If searcing for AI it will return both, and if searching for AI Ethics it will only return AI Ethics.

**I expect if the user searches for AI it will only return an item with an exact tag AI and not AI Ethics.**

UPDATE: I'm posting the most recent version of this filter script as I did make the change from .filter() to .each() and modified it for readablity.

```
        $(function () {
            $('#SelectBox-ByType').change(function () {
                let typeKey = $(this).val();
                if (typeKey) {
                    $('ul.tags').each(function (i, e) {
                        let typeValue = $(this).text();
                        if (typeValue.match(typeKey)) {
                            $(this)
                                .parents('.knowledgeBaseItemWrapper')
                                .removeClass('hideByType');
                        } else {
                            $(this)
                                .parents('.knowledgeBaseItemWrapper')
                                .addClass('hideByType');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.knowledgeBaseItemWrapper')
                        .removeClass('hideByType');
                }
                parseItems.process();
            });
        });
```

I've also tried

```
if (typeValue === typeKey)
```

However this won't work because the list can be long and have many different tags. As soon as one item in the list doesn't match the filter fails even when the correct item is there. At least with .match() I'm getting partially accurate results.

Any ideas on how I might modify this filter to return only an exact match when it's in the list?

**UPDATE:**
The answers so far have focused on filtering each li in the ul. This current function does not have that problem, in its current implementation it works just fine at filtering all li in the ul.

**The question is about parsing individual li when their content starts with a partial match.**

Below is a partial list of the HTML Dropdown menu:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group">
      <label for="SelectBox-ByType">Categories:</label> 
      <div class="select-input">
        <select name="SelectBox-ByType" id="SelectBox-ByType">
        <option value="" selected>Select a Category...</option>
        <option value="AI">AI</option>
        <option value="AI Bias">AI Bias</option>
        <option value="AI Ethics">AI Ethics</option>
        <option value="AI Facial Recognition">AI Facial Recognition</option>
        <option value="Antitrust">Antitrust</option>
        <option value="Augmented Reality">Augmented Reality</option>
        <option value="Big Tech">Big Tech</option>
```

This is an example of the HTML that is being searched:

```
<div class="knowledgeBaseItemWrapper" id="id1529224">
  <div class="knowledgeBaseItem standardContent">
      <div class="summaryWrapper">
          <div class="titleAnchor">...</div>
          <div class="summary">...</div>
          <ul class="tags">
              <li class="tag">AI Facial Recognition</li>
              <li class="tag">Data Privacy</li>
              <li class="tag">Big Tech</li>
          </ul>
```

What I need is a way to parse the content and I suspect that my problem is with the if statement match logic:

```
if (typeValue.match(typeKey))
```

Comment: Please post all the html associated with your question so we can better assist you.  You can use a snippet (edit, CTRL-M) to create a reproducible example - note your comment added to your question points out clearly that the `ul` and `li` being targeted are needed here

Comment: The coment to ROOT's answer was meant to indicate that their solution created a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.startWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) string method, seems the one that you are looking for:

```
$(function () {
  $("#SelectBox-ByType").change(function () {
    let typeKey = $(this).val();
    if (typeKey) {
      $("ul.tags").filter(function (i, e) {
        let typeValue = $(this).text();
        if (typeValue.startWith(typeKey)) {
          $(this)
            .parents(".knowledgeBaseItemWrapper")
            .removeClass("hideByType");
        } else {
          $(this).parents(".knowledgeBaseItemWrapper").addClass("hideByType");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(".knowledgeBaseItemWrapper").removeClass("hideByType");
    }
    parseItems.process();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @ROOT, this answer helps, but although it effectively parses out AI and AI Ethics, it only works when the correct answer is first in the list. I will continue to work with it and see if I can modify other logic to correctly filter all li in the ul. But right now .startsWith() is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$("ul.tags").filter(...)` but that will match the entire `<ul>`, not the individual `<li>` elements that I think you want.

Once you change `"ul.tags"` to `"ul.tags li"`, then `each()` will address the individual `<li>` elements and you can then use `==` instead of `match()` to test them:

```
$(function () {
  $("#SelectBox-ByType").change(function () {
    let typeKey = $(this).val();
    if (typeKey) {
      $("ul.tags li").filter(function (i, e) {
        let typeValue = $(this).text();
        console.log( `Testing whether ${typeValue} == ${typeKey}` );

        if (typeValue == typeKey) {
          console.log( "Yes, they match!" );
          $(this)
            .parents(".knowledgeBaseItemWrapper")
            .removeClass("hideByType");
        } else {
          $(this).parents(".knowledgeBaseItemWrapper").addClass("hideByType");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(".knowledgeBaseItemWrapper").removeClass("hideByType");
    }
    parseItems.process();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `filter()` which says:

> "Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector
>   or pass the function's test."

Once you have that using a form of `a === b` will get the exact match then `.each()` can process those OR you can simply use it like the second example.

Either of these might be simpler but your HTML is not posted to work from.

Note: it is unclear if you require the removal prior to the conditional so I did not do that like:

```
$(this)
    .parents('.knowledgeBaseItemWrapper')
    .toggleClass('hideByType', false);
if (typeKey) {
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SelectBox-ByType').on('change', function() {
    let typeKey = $(this).val();
    if (typeKey) {
      $('ul.tags').filter(function(index) {
          return $(this).text() === typeKey;
        })
        .each(index, element) {
          $(this)
            .parents('.knowledgeBaseItemWrapper')
            .toggleClass('hideByType',true);
        });
    parseItems.process();
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SelectBox-ByType').on('change', function() {
      let typeKey = $(this).val();
      if (typeKey) {
        $('ul.tags').filter(function(index) {
            return $(this).text()=== typeKey;
          })
          .parents('.knowledgeBaseItemWrapper')
          .toggleClass('hideByType');
        parseItems.process();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Both this answer and kmoser's answer are very helpful and have given me some ideas about how to debug this filter. But neither of them have solved the solution so I haven't accepted an answer yet.